# Cannot call the component in route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Basically, I am trying to pass an id value and render the associated data. however, when I want to call the component to render data my route does not call the component.

I have 2 components. (Main and Teams)

Main Component

```
render() {
  const OneTeam = ({match}) => {
  console.log("Never logs this!");
  return (
    /*Let's assume I am returning simple HTML here */
    <p>Hello</p>
  );
};

return (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"
      component={() => <Teams teams={this.props.teams} />}
    />
    <Route path="/:teamId" component={OneTeam} />
  </Switch>
);
```

}

It never goes into **OneTeam** component.

Teams Component

```
 <Link to={`/${team.id}`}>Details</Link>
```

I can pass the id value correctly.

What happens?
As you can see Teams component is my homepage. So here when I click a Team (there is no Team component, you can think of a card), I get the id and with `<Link>` I can push my id to URL (localhost:5001/98), however, nothing else happens. In the Main component,`<Route path ="/:teamId" component={OneTeam}` seems don't work at all because I cannot render OneTeam component, even I am not able to console.log in that component.

I am not sure I am missing something because I just try to do a very basic thing. By the way, I use Redux if it is helpful to figure out. Why I cannot go into OneTeam component or function.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you better?

Comment: I tried to explain the issue a little bit more but I don't know what I can say more.

Comment: try adding `exact` to the home path route

Comment: Oh gosh of course I forgot exact! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should swap the order in which the routes are called. It will render the first route it matches, which is your home and your detail view will never get evaluated. But if you switch the order, the detail view will get evaluated before that and if it matches, it will be rendered.

Comment: Yes because it will not match your home if the id is provided. But if you type in an URL without a match (/test), nothing will be rendered and that would be bad. So it is best to show your home without exact at the end of the switch as fallback.

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to use a parameter on `/`, because it makes it difficult to extend your application to other pages and unnecessarily complex to distinguish whether any other route is a team id or a different page. You should do something like:

```
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      component={() => <Teams teams={this.props.teams} />}
    />
    <Route exact path="/team/:teamId" component={OneTeam} />
```

and then

```
    <Link to={`/team/${team.id}`}>Details</Link>
```

Comment: I already tried that nothing happened. I don't think so the issue is related to that.

Comment: Try including `exact`